# Set the IDs of two parent objects in a nested form / displayed twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 5 Models,

Users, Jobs, Applications, Questions, and Answers

```
Jobs has many questions 
Jobs and Users are associated through Applications
Both Questions and Applications has_many answers.
```

I'm trying to make an Application create action which will --

- Associate a User to a particular job
- Allow the user to answer the questions that the particular job has

Right now, I'm getting it to work, but it's displaying the Question and Answer Twice.

I.e The View comes out as -->

```
This is question one
Text field for question one
This is question two
Text field for question two 
This is question one
Text field for question one
This is question two
Text field for question two
```

This is what my Application#New view looks like -->

```
<% provide(:title, " Apply to this job") %>

<%= form_for [@job, @application]  do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

        <% @job.questions.each do |question| %>

             <%= f.fields_for :answers do |question_field| %>
                    <%= question_field.label :content, question.content %>
                    <%= question_field.text_area :content %>
                    <%= question_field.hidden_field :question_id,  :value => question.id  %>

             <% end %>
        <% end %>


   <%= f.submit "Submit the application", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my Application Controller ->

```
class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_user_and_job


  def new 
   job = params[:job_id]
   @application = Application.build(job)

  end

  def create
    @application = Application.new(application_params)
    @application.save

    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "You have now applied!"

  end

  def edit 
    @application = Application.find(params[:id])

    @answers = []

    @job.questions.each do |question|
      @application.answers.each do |answer|
        @answers << answer if answer.question_id == question.id
      end
    end

  end

  def update
    @application = Application.find(params[:id])

    @application.update_attributes(application_params)
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "You have updated your application!"

  end



  def destroy
    Application.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Application Deleted."
    redirect_to root_url 
  end 

  def show 
    @application = Application.find(params[:id])

    @answers = []

    @job.questions.each do |question|
      @application.answers.each do |answer|
        @answers << answer if answer.question_id == question.id
      end
    end

  end   


private

  def set_user_and_job
      @user = current_user
      @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  end

def application_params
   params.require(:application).permit(:job_id, :user_id, 
     answers_attributes:[:id, :question_id, :content]).merge(user_id: current_user.id,
     job_id: params[:job_id])
end


end
```

This is my Application Model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: applications
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  job_id     :integer
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job
    belongs_to :user
    validates :job_id, presence: true 
    validates :user_id, presence: true 
    has_many :answers
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true


    def self.build(job_id) 
        application = self.new

        job = Job.find(job_id)
        job.questions.count.times do
         application.answers.build
        end

    application
    end

end
```

This is my edit view(fully functioning) ->

```
<% provide(:title, " Edit this application") %>
<%= form_for [@job, @application] do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

         <%= f.fields_for :answers do |question_field| %>
              <%= question_field.label :content, question_field.object.question.content %>
              <%= question_field.text_area :content %>
         <% end %>

   <%= f.submit "Submit the application", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

I think the reason this is happening is that I'm running a double loop, but I'm not sure how else to also get the question id and question content for each answer.

What do you think?

--

Here's how the parameters look, when I run this form ->

```
<%= form_for [@job, @application]  do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <% @job.questions.each do |question| %>

         <%= f.fields_for :answers, question do |question_field| %>
                <%= question_field.label :content, question.content %>
                <%= question_field.text_area :content %>
                <%= question_field.hidden_field :question_id,  :value => question.id  %>

         <% end %>
    <% end %>

   <%= f.submit "Submit the application", class: "button" %>
<% end %>




Started POST "/jobs/3/applications" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-30 14:26:35 +0400
Processing by ApplicationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+gbcaJJjQZ2GfkWiKcOmSf58hf/GEnWonmGrVe1p3ZI=", "application"=>{"question"=>{"content"=>"Sample answer 2", "question_id"=>"6"}}, "commit"=>"Submit the application", "job_id"=>"3"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '69f212609955f368c0f17873b5dce9f506bd3eb7' LIMIT 1
  Job Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "3"]]
Unpermitted parameters: question
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
```

Comment: Are you using the 'new' action to display both the edit and new forms? I'm asking cos I don't see any 'edit' action in your ApplicationsController.

Comment: Hi Gjaldon, I removed it from here to make it a bit easier to read, though one sec, will go right in and update it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   <% @job.questions.each do |question| %>

         <%= f.fields_for :answers, question do |question_field| %>
                <%= question_field.label :content, question.content %>
                <%= question_field.text_area :content %>
                <%= question_field.hidden_field :question_id,  :value => question.id  %>

         <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

This should split up the `f.fields_for` call into [different instances of the object](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)

I think you're basically cycling through the questions, which is then showing *all* the fields, whereas if you make it work for a single instance, it will just show the answer for that question

---

**Maybe Try has_many :through**

Maybe we need to implement `has_many :through` on the answers fields, so that we can create an answer for each question, like this (sorry if I got some associations incorrect):

```
#app/models/question.rb
Class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job

    has_one :answer
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer
end

#app/models/answer.rb
Class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
    belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/application.rb
Class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :job

    has_many :questions, through: job #-> maybe
    has_many :answers, through: :questions #-> maybe
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions

    def self.build(job_id)
       application = self.new

       job = Job.find(job_id)
       job.questions.count.times do
           application.questions.build.build_answer
       end

       application
    end
end

#app/models/job.rb
Class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions

    has_many :applications
    has_many :answers, through: :applications
    has_many :users, through: :applications
end
```

This will give you this view:

```
<%= form_for @application do |f| %>
     <%= f.fields_for :questions do |q| %>
           <%= q.label :content %>
           <%= q.fields_for :answer do |a| %>
                    <%= a.text_area :content %>
           <% end %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You'd have to change your controller to handle the new associations like this:

```
#app/controllers/applications_controller.rb
def new
   job = params[:job_id]
   @application = Application.build(job)
end

private
def application_params
   params.require(:application).permit(:job_id, :user_id, 
     questions_attributes: [answer_attributes:[:content]]).merge(user_id: current_user.id,
     job_id: params[:job_id])
end
```

Comment: Hey Rich, here's something peculiar that's happening. When I try to do this, it ends up causing the NoRecordFound Error. I think the reason is that Rails thinks that the id for the answer is the id for the question. 

If I remove the id, and do it though, it works, but then breaks the edit form.

Comment: One solution could be to have 2 different parameters, one for edit, one for new, but I'm not sure if that's the best solution. What would you suggest?

Comment: Hmmmmm to be honest, I'd have to think about it a little more! You're saying you think Rails is mistaking the `question_id` param for the `id` of the answer?

Comment: There is another thing that could cause the issue. You're building the objects on `new`, but what about `edit`? Maybe this has something to do with it

Comment: Yeah, kind of. I think question_field is actually using the question object, rather then the answer object. For example, if I type in - <%=  question_field.text_area :content %>, Rails pops in the default value of question.content, rather then the empty value of answer.content. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: Also went ahead popped in the edit action so it's here. Will also go in and put up the view.

Comment: Ohhhhh yeah I get it - what params are you getting back, can you post them?

Comment: From what you've said, it seems the thing is focused on the Question object, rather than answers. Maybe we could make a has_many :through relationship, whereby the answers will be `through` another model? Let me write some code to demonstrate

Comment: Sounds interesting, looking forward to learning! Also updated the question to show the params that Rails sends back

Comment: Hey @StepanParunashvili, thanks for the params. Looking at them, it seems you're correct - it's passing the question object, rather than the answer. I think if we can implement a `has_many :through`, it will solve your problem; but getting it right will take some thought

Comment: Rich sensei, HUGE props. This is making more sense :). Okay, I'll try to implement this, and get back with the results

Comment: No problem! I had a feeling my last iteration wasn't quite right, but this definitely feels closer to a solution. Eager to hear your progress! It will be good to chat about it too

Comment: Hmm, and the plot thickens. The way it's set, The admin user creates questions when they create a job. How would we go about also making the questions have the ID for each application? 

I'm guessing in the controller, when we write application.new, 
we can also do something like jobs.questions.each do | question | .

question.application_id = @application.id ? But the application won't have an id until it's created. 

Am I overthinking this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44149/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-stepan-parunashvili)